# Google maps v2 vs. v3

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I am using mostly google maps version 2 on my pages, but now I am trying to work from an example which is v3.  Should that be ok?  Will it have any strange effects on my application?

What is the best way to smoothly upgrade in versions of google maps in an application?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use examples using v3 but always check them against the v2 API reference or you'll meet unexpected results at some point.

Upgrade is always a pain but here are a two suggestions:

1. [Problems in upgrading to v3 from v2 of google maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838979/problems-in-upgrading-to-v3-from-v2-of-google-maps-api)
2. [Yichi's Tips for upgrading](http://yichixu.blogspot.com/2010/12/tips-in-upgrading-google-map-code-from.html)