# Google maps V3 directions service fails to find roads close to selected point resulting in wrong directions

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Greetings,

Until now I have mostly been working with google maps v2. I am now making my way to v3, but I came across a problem I havent been able to find a solution for.

In V2, when using directions, I could add a point on the map with no actual road, and the maps api would automatically figure out the closest possible endpoint where a road exists and display directrions to that point. This seems not to be the case with V3 though. In allot of cases the route is wrong, because I haven't placed my point on an actual road and the service fails (?) to find the closest one. Here is a screenshot to display what I mean:

[image]

I am using the exact same coordinates for both maps. The red pins on V3 show where those coordinates actually point to, but as you can see the directions are wrong. Only if I use coordinates that are exactly on a road, then they show up correctly (not displayed here). I am using the exact same coordinates on V2 and V3, but only V2 displays the correct directions.

Here is a sample of the code I am using for getting the direcrtions:

```
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
    //Works fine, so I ommit the code
}


function calcRoute(endpointCoords) // endpointCoords holds coordinates for end point
{
    var startpoint = '<?=$startPoint[latitude];?>, <?=$startPoint[longitude];?>';
    var endpoint = endpointCoords;

    var request = {
    origin:startpoint,
    destination:endpoint,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status){
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
        {   
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}
```

The documentation did not help me much further ( http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Directions )

Have you had similar experience with the v3 version of the api? Any ideas why this happens?

UPDATE: Here is a link that shows the code and problem in action: 
http://jsfiddle.net/spairus/gNpZ2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the graphic, it looks like your lng/lat might be in the wrong order. As [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838979/problems-in-upgrading-to-v3-from-v2-of-google-maps-api), you might want to make sure you are using the longitude and latitude in the correct order.

Comment: Hello emzy, no that is not the case: as I said, on the right image (v3) the red pins indicate the points that the lan/lon values I am using represent, and the directions are using the exact same lat/lon values, but the start and end points are wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry. Would you be able to point me to a hosted link of your code? I don't have a wrapper handy...

Comment: Hi, here is a link to code that represents exactly the above example http://jsfiddle.net/spairus/gNpZ2/ . You will note that I am using the exact same coordinates for markers and directions. The markers are correct in place, the directions are not!

Comment: Instead of startpoint and endpoint, use the previously defined point1 and point2. They have to be of LatLng type. http://jsfiddle.net/gNpZ2/1/

Comment: now I feel stupid :) thing is I first tried it on my application this way but it would just not work (nothing showed up on the map and no error messages either). It works in the example I sent you so something does not work as it should on my app :/ Thanks!

Comment: And here was the problem as I just found out... I was using single quotes in the LatLng parameter: var startpoint = new google.maps.LatLng('36.2556200, 28.166096'); It seems it does not work when using those, it has to be without (i.e. var startpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(36.2556200, 28.166096); ).

Comment: Good catch - I often overlook those myself :)